# How to choose random files from a folder

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to organise my dataset for classifiction in the folowing way

```
|-- train
     |-- cats
     |-- dogs
|-- validation
     |-- cats
     |-- dogs
```

I found an article where it is done like this

for the train folder

```
   search for cat images and move them to the cats folder and do the same for dog images
```

then for the validation folder

```
  search for image id ranging from 5000–5999
```

But for the validation set i wanted random images from the whole dogs or cats folder so i tried this

```
for i in range(1000):
    random_file=random.choice(os.listdir(train_cats_dir))
    shutil.move(f'{train_cats_dir}/{random_file}',val_cats_dir)
```

But it takes around 3 mins to go through the loop and have to do it again for the dog folder.  I also tried putting os.listdir(train_cats_dir) in a variable and use it once  but it chooses a file twice.

So what would be a faster way of doing this?

I am new to pytorch and trying to use the Imagefolder method

Comment: why do you **move** files just to choose file?

Comment: Instead of reading the files every time you run the for loop, read the files and store in a list. and take random file from the list.